# How do you save a file from S3 using the AWS iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I'm looking for a super simple example of how to do a `getObject` from S3 using their iOS SDK: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/

Specifically the part on how to write the response results to a file.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that although `S3GetObjectReponse` has `setOutputStream`, the only
way to get `S3GetObjectResponse` is via  `[[AmazonClientManager s3] getObject:getObjectRequest];`
And it might be too late by then.

So, set the output stream in the request:

```
S3GetObjectRequest  *getObjectRequest  = [[[S3GetObjectRequest alloc]  ....];
getObjectRequest.outputStream = ...;
```

### See `S3GetObjectRequest`:

> ```
> - (NSOutputStream *) outputStream
> ```
>
> [`read`, `write`, `assign`]
>
> Gets and Sets the output stream for the response data.

If this is set, then the response will write the data to the supplied stream instead of making it available through the data property.

### The stream must be opened and scheduled in the desired runloop. The SDK will not close the stream.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the API documentation for `S3GetObjectResponse.h`:

```
00020 @interface S3GetObjectResponse : S3Response {
00021         NSString *contentType;
00022         NSMutableDictionary *metadata;
00023         NSOutputStream *outputStream;
00024 }
00025 
00027 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* contentType;
00028 
00033 -(NSString *)getMetadataForKey:(NSString *)aKey;
00034 
00041 -(void)setOutputStream:(NSOutputStream *)stream;
```

Perhaps you can set the S3 response's `NSOutputStream` using its `-setOutputStream:` method. You could then perhaps write that stream to a file using one of the [`NSOutputStream` instance methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html). For iOS apps, you can write data to a file in one of [three specific folders](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW10).